# ember this.get Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Window> has no method 'get'

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I am trying to get this code working in ember but it keeps giving me 
"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'get'" on line 
`this.get('element_id')[item.id] = true;` why can't it access the element_id hash?

```
function() {
    return Ember.ArrayProxy.extend({
        box: null,
        content: [],
        element_id: {},

        init: function() {
            this._super();
            var items = this.get( 'box' ).getData();
            if ( items.get( 'length' ) ) {
                this.set( '[]', items );
            };

            // Initialize the hash
            items.forEach(function(item) {
                this.get('element_id')[item.id] = true;
            });             

        }
    });
}
```

);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the [forEach](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_forEach) method, you can pass a target object that will be set as `this` on the context, as explained in the documentation:

> Note that in addition to a callback, you can also pass an optional target object that will be set as "this" on the context. This is a good way to give your iterator function access to the current object.

So your code should be now:

```
items.forEach(function(item) {
  this.get('element_id')[item.id] = true;
}, this);
```

Comment: quick related question, when you use getJSON, also this doesn't work, right now I am declaring outside of getson a var backup = this;  Is there a similar way?

Comment: AFAIK, no, you effectively have to use a closure for that. A common naming convention in js is `var that = this;`.

Comment: do you know is this very bad for application memory consumption is this duplicating big chunks of data or is it using proper pointers?

Comment: again, I'm not 100% sure, but normally, it just keeps the same object and make it accessible through the "nested" function. So I think you can do it safely.